# When is an ellipsis needed when dealing with parameter packs?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I'm trying to understand [some code from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply). The relevant part is here

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::tuple<Ts...> const& theTuple)
{
    std::apply
    (
        [&os](Ts const&... tupleArgs)
        {
            os << '[';
            std::size_t n{ 0 };
            ((os << tupleArgs << (++n != sizeof...(Ts) ? ", " : "")), ...);
            os << ']';
        }, theTuple
    );
    return os;
}
```

If I'm interpretting the above correctly `((os << tupleArgs << (++n != sizeof...(Ts) ? ", " : "")), ...)` is a fold-expression over the comma operator. Semantically it is`([some pattern involving the parameter pack's values] , ...)` which means to fold with comma.

What I don't get however is why the `sizeof` in there is a `sizeof...`? To me ellipsis means expand, but we don't want to expand there. `Ts` is like an aggregate type, akin to a tuple, we just want the size at compile time of that aggregate type while the compiler evaluates the fold. And indeed in Visual Studio it works either way, with or without the ellipsis. Same in GCC, Godbolt tells me. (EDIT: actually I am wrong without the ellipsis it compiles but the output contains a trailing comma that should not be there)

Is the rule to just always use `sizeof...` if you want the size of a parameter pack?

Comment: See [`sizeof...`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...)

Comment: *"And indeed in Visual Studio it works either way, with or without the ellipsis"* - I suspect your testing wasn't entirely thorough.

Comment: ah my mistake. there is a trailing comma that should not be there in the output. I was just surprised that it compiled and did not notice

Comment: so `sizeof(Ts)` will return the size of individual types when expanded and `sizeof...(Ts)` returns the size of the pack?

Comment: Yup. That sums it up.

Comment: somebody answer that way and ill accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ellipses are needed there because `sizeof...(Ts)` is a special form of `sizeof` that returns the size of a parameter pack. Ordinary `sizeof(Ts)` could not be used for this purpose because it needs to remain possible to use standard `sizeof` behavior in expanded patterns i.e. `sizeof(Ts)` returns the size of an individual type in an evaluated fold expression.